# SLF4J Warning about multiple bindings

Tags: java, eclipse, binding, slf4j

I try to learn RCP and want to  do [this](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/eclipse-rcp-tutorial-add-a-menu-item-to-the-popup-menu-when-right-click-a-file/) but when I click run then i got multiple binding

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://940.fwk970900790:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://940.fwk970900790:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks,
patrio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple issue in your environment

1. Are you sure you have only **slf4j.jar** in your class path?
2. It may be possible if you are using **Maven** other jar file including that **slf4j.jar** in your project.
3. Be sure latest **slf4j.jar** should be first in eclipse classpath.

For Maven User do this

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Comment: 1. I don't see any slf4j in my class patch.
2. I don't use Maven

Comment: What ever way you are compiling your project make sure multiple slf4j.jar not be there

Comment: I'm not sure haw to check it. Can you tell me?

Comment: Which IDE you are using how you compiling the project ? Its a Java or Web project ?

Comment: I do all like in tutorial that I linked

Comment: Check here `Right click on Project->Project->Java Build Path->Libraries` see what all `jar` files used by your project

Comment: I did like you said and I don't have any slf4j.jar there